# Vite is not compiling my dynamic imports using vite-plugin-dynamic-import | JSX files

Tags: vite, vite-reactjs, vite-plugin-development

vite-plugin-dynamic-import is not working for JSX Files.

`component: import(`./pages${route}.js`),`

It working with .js extension but not working with.jsx

Please help me, i have been stuck here for 2 days.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: hi @SmurtiranjanSahoo welcome to SO. can you please provide more clearity? or pls share the what you have tried so far. also share the error message or logs etc